# How do I get the index of a list item during a click even on that item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the index of a list item during a click even on that item?

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
<ul>

$('li').live('click', function(e){
    alert(e.index);
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).delegate('li', 'click', function () {
    alert($(this)).index());
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xERTx/1/

`.live()` is now depreciated as of jQuery 1.7 in favor of `.on()` and `.delegate()` (source: http://api.jquery.com/live).

Comment: Good to know, how does .on and .delegate differ from .live?

Comment: @fancy `$(<selector>).live(<event>, <callback>)` was essentially `$(document).delegate(<selector, <event>, <callback>)`. But `.delegate()` gives you the ability to set a different root element which helps out performance wise.

Comment: +1 but it looks like you have one extra $() call compared to your fiddle

Comment: It looks as if .bind(), .delegate(), and .live() are all be depreciated soon for .on() `As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), .delegate(), and .live(). `

Comment: They have been `superseded` but not depreciated. In future versions of jQuery you can expect that `.live()` will not be included but `.bind()` and `.delegate()` will be (they each take a single line in the core). That being said, yes, `.on()` does it all with slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the index keyword?

http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
$(e.target).index( $(e.target).parent() );
```

Answer (score 0):

solution here

http://jsfiddle.net/SMpWs/1/

```
$('li').click(function() {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```